# Setting values in pandas df using location

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as such:

```
df_pos = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[5,4,3,6,0,7,1,2], [2,5,3,6,4,7,1,0]]
)
df_value = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[np.arange(10 + i, 50 + i, 5) for i in range(0,2)]
)
```

and I want to have a new dataframe `df_final` where df_pos notates the position and df_value the corresponding value.

I can do it like this:

```
df_value_copy = df_value.copy()
for i in range(len(df_pos)):
    df_value_copy.iloc[i, df_pos.iloc[i, :]] = df_value.iloc[i].values
df_final = df_value_copy
```

However, I have very large dataframes that would be way too slow. Therefore I want to see whether there is any smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also try [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis) to place `df_value` into `df_final` based on the `df_pos`:

```
df_final = df_value.copy()
np.put_along_axis(
    arr=df_final.values,     # Destination Arr
    indices=df_pos.values,   # Indices 
    values=df_value.values,  # Source Values
    axis=1                   # Along Axis
)
```

The arguments do not need to be kwargs can be positional like:

```
df_final = df_value.copy()
np.put_along_axis(df_final.values, df_pos.values, df_value.values, 1)
```

`df_final`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0  30  40  45  20  15  10  25  35
1  46  41  11  21  31  16  26  36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting values with numpy [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
df_final = df_value.copy()
df_final.values[np.arange(len(df_pos))[:,None], df_pos.values] = df_value.values

df_final
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0  30  40  45  20  15  10  25  35
1  46  41  11  21  31  16  26  36
```